# Can’t see the line.new object in TradingView alerts menu to build a multi argument alert (is less, greater etc.)

Tags: pine-script

- Hey.. So I am trying out a few great studies that I find on TradingView and are open source. I found this nice Volume Profile and now Im like very eager to customize the hek out of it. Iam stuck finding a way how to call the line.new object that is being drawn. I cant create an alert around it. TradingView doesnt even see the study in its alerts section. Ive tried the usual plot this, alertcondition that...but ...and it took me a while to figure out those lines on the chart are by the line.new.... (still learning pine and this already is version 4 here..yikes)

Long story/ Short story: How can I modify the code below (probably at the very bottom “draw plot” section) .. so that TradingView Alerts, can see and are able to see and can interact with the object coming from the “line.new” Volume Profile study?...

Thx in advance. Sid

```
//@version=4
study(title='Testing', overlay=true, max_lines_count=30)

showLines = input(title="Show Lines ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

BARS_BACK = 20
line bullLine1 = na //bull line
if showLines == true and barstate.islast
//Loop to plot a line
for i = BARS_BACK to 0                
    bullishcase = close[i+1] > high[i+2]

    if bullishcase
        bullLine1 := line.new(x1=bar_index[i + 2], y1=high[i + 2], x2=bar_index[i], y2=high[i + 2], extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
```

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: As per request for something less lines in code with same issue: please see code above.. THX